# why do we call the constant of integration a constant when really its an unknown variable??

Tags: integration, derivatives, philosophy

when I started learning integration and my teacher called "C" a constant I questioned her and asked why we call it a constant when the value is never constant, hoping someone can shed some light on this?

Comment: It is constant *with respect to the variable of integration*.

Comment: The difference between any two antiderivatives of a function is constant, even if you don’t happen to know it's exact value.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're the amount that you're adding to the antiderivative is constant with respect to the independent variable.

For example in $\int 2xdx=x^2+C$, the $x^2$ part varies with $x$. The $C$ part doesn't.